# strptime -- Invalid Date Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be super simple, but I am stumped:

```rb
require 'time'
# works fine, prints "2/20/2012 6:46:00 PM"
puts Time.new(2012,2,20,18,46,0).strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y %-l:%M:%S %p')
test_date = '2/20/2012 6:46:00 PM'
# Invalid date error -- why??
# What am I doing wrong in my usage of strptime?
last_login = DateTime.strptime(test_date, '%-m/%-d/%Y %-l:%M:%S %p')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there is a little difference between `strptime` and `strftime`. I don't think you need `-` in `strptime`.

```
test_date = '2/20/2012 6:46:00 PM'
last_login = DateTime.strptime(test_date, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p')
```

Comment: hah, that is the kind of inconsistency i expect of php, not ruby

Comment: If you think about it though, the `-` flag makes sense when formatting a date but not when parsing one.

Comment: Old, but worth commenting. It make "sense" but it silly for it to throw an error because the user was specific about formatting in a documented way. It should do what one expects it to do, not throw an error.

Comment: this saved me a lot of headaches